# How to use custom property name for foreign key column in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I for some reason cannot seem to find this info anywhere, but feel this would be a common thing. I originally had this class:

```
public class SiteSharingPermission
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

I recently needed to modify this column / property (`OrganizationId -> PartnerOrganizationId`) but I'm having an issue with my migrations on updating the foreign key column property name.

I tried running migrations, modified the up/down to this:

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_SiteSharingPermissions_Organizations_OrganizationId",
            table: "SiteSharingPermissions");

        migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
            name: "OrganizationId",
            table: "SiteSharingPermissions",
            newName: "PartnerOrganizationId");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_SiteSharingPermissions_Organizations_PartnerOrganizationId",
            table: "SiteSharingPermissions",
            column: "PartnerOrganizationId",
            principalTable: "Organizations",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_SiteSharingPermissions_Organizations_PartnerOrganizationId",
            table: "SiteSharingPermissions");

        migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
            name: "PartnerOrganizationId",
            table: "SiteSharingPermissions",
            newName: "OrganizationId");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_SiteSharingPermissions_Organizations_OrganizationId",
            table: "SiteSharingPermissions",
            column: "OrganizationId",
            principalTable: "Organizations",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    }
```

But I keep getting an error when trying to get results from this table:

> Unknown column 's.OrganizationId' in field list

Any ideas?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=data-annotations%2Cdata-annotations-simple-key%2Csimple-key#foreign-key But maybe you have some raw sql? Perhaps in a view / procedure / trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally won't prefer making changes to migration file. Instead do something like below.

```
public class SiteSharingPermission
{
   [Required]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   public Guid PartnerOrganizationId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("PartnerOrganizationId")]
   public Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

You can also do it using Fluent API method.

Comment: Wow, I did not expect it to be that easy, thank you Akash Veer!